# Is there an algorithm that, given a list of integers, returns a list of integers of size N where the total value is V±100?

Tags: javascript, algorithm

Given a list of integers, how would I be able to return a list of integers of **size N** where the **total sum of the integers is equal to V±100**?

For example, if I have a list of integers `list = [652, 840, 585, 147, 652, 576, 786, 362, 800, 591]`, how could I return a list of integers of **size 21** with a total value between **11,500 and 11,700** as **V = 11,600** and **N = 21**? And in this scenario, it would be ok to repeat an integer more than once.

I tried doing a little googling but couldn't find what I was looking for.

I'd prefer a solution in JavaScript but any language is fine.

Comment: You forgot to post the code that you've already written trying to solve this problem, as well as a description of the part that is causing you problems.

Comment: Look for coin change problem

Comment: Contrary to what @MBo said, this has nothing to do with the coin change problem.  It is actually a surprisingly tricky dynamic programming problem.

Comment: @btilly This problem might be considered as generalization of coin change with defined coint quantity, DP table might be extended by 100. I mentioned coin change rather than subset sum because the same values might be uses repeatedly. I believe that these problems are rather close.

Comment: @MBo The "minimum number" vs "fixed number" turns out to be more important than whether or not you repeat values.

Comment: @btilly Well, now I see that you emphasize on "minimum number" property that I considered as second-order thing compared with repeat values.

Comment: @MBo Having googled "coin change problem", I now see your point.  The DP solution to that is similar to a solution to this.  That said, I'm surprised that nobody discusses using an A* search for the coin change problem.  In the normal real-world case, this finds the greedy solution and is done.  Its worst case is worse than DP, but still pseudo-polynomial.  And "smallest number" turns into "shortest path" very naturally.

Comment: To see what I mean about A* search, sort your array of currencies by descending size.  The nodes in your graph are `(value, i)` where `value` is how much money you still have and `i` is the largest coin you are planning to use.  Your heuristic function is `ceil(value / c[i])`.  And below `(value, i)` are the nodes `(value - c[i], i)` and (if any currencies are left) `(value, i+1)`.  The cost of the first edge is 1 and the second is 0.  (The first edge you use a coin, the second you use no coin but change your mind.)  Start at `(target_value, 0)` and do your search to get to `(0, len(c)-1)`.

Answer (score 0):

The idea of the solution to this is similar to the dynamic programming solution to the [Subset Sum problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subset_sum_problem).

I won't give you code.  But I will give you the exact approach.

The "within 100" is a red herring.  You are better off simply going for "closest".  Then verifying whether or not you got an answer within 100 of the target.  (As it happens, in this case you can hit the target sum on the nose.)

The idea is that for `n` in `0..N` you want to build a data structure mapping values that you can get with `n` integers to a path by which you could get there.  For `n=0` this is easy - your data structure is just `{0: null}`.  (You can get to 0 with an empty sum.)

For `n=1` you will wind up with a data structure with entries like `840: [840, [null]]`.

For `n=2` you will wind up with a data structure with entries like `1680: [840, [840, [null]]]`.

When you have reached `n=21` you can extract the closest solution with:

```
let bestValue = null;
Object.keys(solution).forEach(function (value) {
    if (bestValue == null) {
        bestValue = value*1; // The *1 casts a string to a number.
    }
    else if (Math.abs(targetSum - value) < Math.abs(targetSum - bestValue)) {
        bestValue = value*1;
    }
});

let bestSolution = solution[bestValue];

// We have the bestSolution as a linked list.  Recover it as an array.
let answer = [];
while (bestSolution) {
    answer.push(bestSolution[0]);
    bestSolution = bestSolution[1];
}
```

In your specific solution the final answer will be something like:

```
[
  147, 147, 147, 147, 147,
  147, 147, 147, 652, 652,
  800, 800, 800, 840, 840,
  840, 840, 840, 840, 840,
  840
]
```